# In Aptana Studio (eclipse rcp) is the bundle 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins' set to auto start?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, aptana, aptana3, p2

In [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com) (An Eclipse RCP) is the bundle **org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins** is set to auto start?

Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.3.1.201212171919

The plugin is listed in **[eclipse]/plugins/org.eclipse....**

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.100.v20110815-1419.jar
```

Aptana 3.3.x is not loading dropin plugins located in the dropins folder.

The [P2 information](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started) states that *"If you are attempting to use dropins, but your bundles are not being found, first ensure org.eclipse.equinox.ds and org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins are marked to auto-start. "*

What logfile, or configuration file can confirm that the bundle listed above is running?

Note: This may be a regression, because it happened before to [Aptana in 3.1.1](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4682?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel)

Comment: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins (1.1.100.v20110815-1419) "Equinox Provisioning Drop-in" [Resolved]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration of Eclipse (config.ini) you must manually start the dropins because it is not autostarted by the Aptana Studio RCP application definition. Note: In the standard Eclipse Distro it is started.

```
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins@2:start
```

Once added, the configuration file Aptana->About->Installation Details->Configuration should now have this listed plugin as "Active" rather than "Resolved"

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins (1.1.100.v20110815-1419) "Equinox Provisioning Drop-in" [Active]
```